# List IP addresses connected to AWS cache cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached

Is it possible to get a list of IP addresses connected to an AWS Elastic Cache Memcached cluster?

Comment: Are you asking about Public or Private IP addresses?

Comment: Both public and private to the AWS VPC group.

Answer (score 0):

The private IP addresses are associated with Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs) within the VPC. Therefore, list the ENIs and (I presume) use tags/names to identify which ones are associated with the ElastiCache cluster.

From [Amazon ElastiCache FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/faqs/):

> Please note that, we strongly recommend you use the **DNS Names** to connect to your nodes as the underlying IP addresses can change (e.g., after cache node replacement).

Amazon ElastiCache clusters are designed to be accessed only within the same VPC so they do not have Public IP addresses. If you wish to access it from outside of a VPC, see: [Accessing ElastiCache Resources from Outside AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html)